# Datastax Cassandra 2.2.5: Change Logging Location (logback)

Tags: cassandra, datastax

i am using datastax cassandra 2.2.5 on a ubuntu server.
The logging configuration seems to be in the "/etc/cassandra/logback.xml" file. In this xml, the destination folder for the log files is set via the **"${cassandra.logdir}"** property. Where should i configure/change this property so that i can give a custom folder location? I do 'not' want my logs to go to the default location "/var/log/cassandra".

I also tried updated the cassandra-env.sh, with 
**"JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.logdir=/data/log"** 
But now there are two system setting with different  folders. Thus my folder location is not overriding the default folder.
Thanks
jaskaran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after reading the logback docs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution

It says that variables in **logback.xml** are resolved against different scope, in this order:

- local scope
- context scope
- system scope

In our case, it's is the system scope that is used.

The **cassandra.logdir** is set inside the `/usr/sbin/cassandra` exec file itself:

```
launch_service()
{
    pidpath="$1"
    foreground="$2"
    props="$3"
    class="$4"
    cassandra_parms="-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml"
    cassandra_parms="$cassandra_parms -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra"
    cassandra_parms="$cassandra_parms -Dcassandra.storagedir=$cassandra_storagedir"
...
...
```

As you can see, the **storagedir** variable can be defined by user (in the file `/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh`) but it seems that **`cassandra.logdir`** is hard-coded.

Just change it there or add a variable `$cassandra.logdir` so you can defined it in `/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh` which is less instrusive than modifying the cassandra exec

Comment: Thank you very much doanduyhai. It works by directly updating the  "/usr/sbin/cassandra" exec file. But does not seem to work via the less intrusive approach "add a variable $cassandra.logdir so you can defined it in /usr/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh which is less instrusive than modifying the cassandra exec"